# Misunderstanding regarding CVE

Tags: cve

I was learning about CVE and went through this :

> ... if you own a security tool whose reports contain references to CVE
>   IDs, you may then access fix information in a separate database that
>   is compatible with CVE ...

source: https://cve.mitre.org/about/faqs.html#public_use

I can't understand what that database related thing in that statement. 
I was thinking if CVE is itself vulnerabilities database but this is said to be not

Can anyone also help me understand better on that and explain:

> Isn't CVE just another vulnerability database?
>
> No. CVE is not a vulnerability database. CVE is designed to allow
>   vulnerability databases and other capabilities to be linked together,
>   and to facilitate the comparison of security tools and services

source: https://cve.mitre.org/about/faqs.html#is_cve_another_vulnerability_database

Comment: If you are quoting something, please include a link so that we can understand.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a security question, but more of a comprehension question. The "database related thing" is the ***fix*** database they mentioned as an example. As the FAQ explains, CVE is not a database, but a way to describe and reference vulnerabilities and exposures.

Comment: i font understand you last line ccould you please explain it ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are CVE counts a good indicator of a software's security?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/147111/are-cve-counts-a-good-indicator-of-a-softwares-security). While the question might not be the same, the answer given by Arminius should also clear up your misunderstandings.